# Create a unique name from non-unique names within id groups

Tags: r, dplyr

Within *id*, my data has multiple non-unique *name* labels.  I would like to create a third column such that non-unique names have a letter pasted to end of the name to create a unique name.

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c("172262", "172262", "172262", "172262", 
"172504", "172504", "172504", "172507", "172507", "172507"), 
    name = c("Fam", "Fam", "Fam", "CM_fam", "CBT_Fam", "CBT_Fam", 
    "CBT_Fam", "TAU", "CBT_Educ", "CBT_MI")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

The desired output is:

```
id     name     unique_name    
172262 Fam      Fam_a      
172262 Fam      Fam_b      
172262 Fam      Fam_c      
172262 CM_fam   CM_fam    
172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam_a  
172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam_b  
172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam_c  
172507 TAU      TAU       
172507 CBT_Educ CBT_Educ  
172507 CBT_MI   CBT_MI
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `paste` or `sprintf` with `letters`...

```
dat %>% group_by(id, name) %>% mutate(uname = 
  if (n() > 1) sprintf("%s_%s", name, letters[row_number()]) 
  else name
)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   id, name [6]
   id     name     uname    
   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>    
 1 172262 Fam      Fam_a    
 2 172262 Fam      Fam_b    
 3 172262 Fam      Fam_c    
 4 172262 CM_fam   CM_fam   
 5 172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam_a
 6 172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam_b
 7 172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam_c
 8 172507 TAU      TAU      
 9 172507 CBT_Educ CBT_Educ 
10 172507 CBT_MI   CBT_MI
```

For other string operations in the tidyverse (which dplyr belongs to), maybe see stringr and glue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ave` (base `R`)

```
transform(dat, unique_name = 
            ave(name,name, FUN = function(x) {
              if((l <- length(x)) == 1) x
              else paste0(x,"_",letters[seq(l)])
            }))
#        id     name unique_name
# 1  172262      Fam       Fam_a
# 2  172262      Fam       Fam_b
# 3  172262      Fam       Fam_c
# 4  172262   CM_fam      CM_fam
# 5  172504  CBT_Fam   CBT_Fam_a
# 6  172504  CBT_Fam   CBT_Fam_b
# 7  172504  CBT_Fam   CBT_Fam_c
# 8  172507      TAU         TAU
# 9  172507 CBT_Educ    CBT_Educ
# 10 172507   CBT_MI      CBT_MI
```

And another one for the code golf, though not general :

```
dat$unique_name <- chartr(
  make.unique(dat$name,sep="_"),old="123456789",new="abcdefghi")
dat
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#        id     name unique_name
#     <chr>    <chr>       <chr>
#  1 172262      Fam         Fam
#  2 172262      Fam       Fam_a
#  3 172262      Fam       Fam_b
#  4 172262   CM_fam      CM_fam
#  5 172504  CBT_Fam     CBT_Fam
#  6 172504  CBT_Fam   CBT_Fam_a
#  7 172504  CBT_Fam   CBT_Fam_b
#  8 172507      TAU         TAU
#  9 172507 CBT_Educ    CBT_Educ
# 10 172507   CBT_MI      CBT_MI
```

Answer (score 1):

A different `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
 dat %>%
 group_by(id, name) %>%
 mutate(unique_name = if(n() > 1) paste(name, letters[1:length(name)], sep = "_") else name)

   id     name     unique_name
   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>      
 1 172262 Fam      Fam_a      
 2 172262 Fam      Fam_b      
 3 172262 Fam      Fam_c      
 4 172262 CM_fam   CM_fam     
 5 172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam_a  
 6 172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam_b  
 7 172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam_c  
 8 172507 TAU      TAU        
 9 172507 CBT_Educ CBT_Educ   
10 172507 CBT_MI   CBT_MI
```

First, it group by "id" and "name". Then, if the number of cases per group is more than 1, it combines the value from "name" with the sequence of letters of length of "name", otherwise it assigns the value from "name".

Or using `length()` instead of `n()`:

```
dat %>%
 group_by(id, name) %>%
 mutate(unique_name = if(length(name) > 1) paste(name, letters[1:length(name)], sep = "_") else name)
```

Or with `seq_along()` instead of `n()`:

```
dat %>%
 group_by(id, name) %>%
 mutate(unique_name = if(any(seq_along(name) != 1)) paste(name, letters[1:length(name)], sep = "_") else name)
```

Or a slightly different approach using `gl()` for generating the letters:

```
dat %>%
 group_by(id, name) %>%
 mutate(unique_name = if(n() > 1) paste(name, gl(length(name), 1, n(), letters), sep = "_") else name) 

   id     name     unique_name
   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>      
 1 172262 Fam      Fam_a      
 2 172262 Fam      Fam_b      
 3 172262 Fam      Fam_c      
 4 172262 CM_fam   CM_fam     
 5 172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam_a  
 6 172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam_b  
 7 172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam_c  
 8 172507 TAU      TAU        
 9 172507 CBT_Educ CBT_Educ   
10 172507 CBT_MI   CBT_MI
```

Or:

```
dat %>%
 group_by(id, name) %>%
 mutate(unique_name = if(length(name) > 1) paste(name, gl(length(name), 1, n(), letters), sep = "_") else name)
```

Or:

```
dat %>%
 group_by(id, name) %>%
 mutate(unique_name = if(any(seq_along(name) != 1)) paste(name, gl(length(name), 1, n(), letters), sep = "_") else name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to bring some data.table flavor here:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
DT[, unique_name := if (.N > 1) paste(name, letters[1:.N], sep = "_") 
                    else name, 
   by = .(id, name)]
```

Although, as others have pointed out, you might want to replace `letters[1:.N]` to just `1:.N` in case you have more than 26 duplicate names.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of options to choose from here, but if you are looking for a fairly simple pipeline, and are okay with a somewhat different formatted output, you can make use of `make.unique` from base R:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(id, name) %>% 
  mutate(unique_name = make.unique(name))
```

Which yields:

```
   id     name     unique_name
   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>      
 1 172262 Fam      Fam        
 2 172262 Fam      Fam.1      
 3 172262 Fam      Fam.2      
 4 172262 CM_fam   CM_fam     
 5 172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam    
 6 172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam.1  
 7 172504 CBT_Fam  CBT_Fam.2  
 8 172507 TAU      TAU        
 9 172507 CBT_Educ CBT_Educ   
10 172507 CBT_MI   CBT_MI
```